# Registration Form for a social network website - unable to store gender and birthday values

Tags: php, session, authentication, store

In case any error message in displayed in registration, all field like first name, email, etc store their value and need not be refilled. I am unable to add same functionality for birthday and gender option.
Following is the coding, please tell me how to store their values as well so that their value remains in session as well

```
<?php 
    require 'config/config.php';
    require 'includes/form_handlers/register_handler.php';
    require 'includes/form_handlers/login_handler.php';
?>

<html>

<head>
    <title>registration form</title>
</head>

<body>

    <form action="register.php" method="POST">
        <input type="email" name="log_email" placeholder="Email Address" 
         value="<?php 
        if(isset($_SESSION['log_email'])){
            echo $_SESSION['log_email'];
        } 
        ?>" required>
        <br>
        <input type="password" name="log_password" placeholder="Password" 
        required>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" name="login_button" value="Login">
        <br>

        <?php if(in_array("Email or password was incorrect<br>", $error_array))
            echo "Email or password was incorrect<br>"; 
        ?>

    </form>

    <form action="register.php" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="reg_fname" placeholder="First Name" value="<?php 
        if(isset($_SESSION['reg_fname'])){
            echo $_SESSION['reg_fname'];
        } 
        ?>" required>
        <br>
        <?php if(in_array("Your first name must be between 2 and 30 characters<br>", $error_array)) 
                    echo "Your first name must be between 2 and 30 characters<br>"; ?>


        <input type="text" name="reg_lname" placeholder="Last Name" value="<?php 
        if(isset($_SESSION['reg_lname'])){
            echo $_SESSION['reg_lname'];
        } 
        ?>" required>
        <br>
        <?php if(in_array("Your last name must be between 2 and 30 characters<br>", $error_array)) 
                    echo "Your last name must be between 2 and 30 characters<br>"; ?>


        <input type="email" name="reg_email" placeholder="Email" value="<?php 
        if(isset($_SESSION['reg_email'])){
            echo $_SESSION['reg_email'];
        } 
        ?>" required>
        <br>


        <input type="email" name="reg_email2" placeholder="Confirm Email" value="<?php 
        if(isset($_SESSION['reg_email2'])){
            echo $_SESSION['reg_email2'];
        } 
        ?>" required>
        <br>
        <?php if(in_array("Email already in use<br>", $error_array)) 
                    echo "Email already in use<br>";
              else if(in_array("Invalid email format<br>", $error_array)) 
                    echo "Invalid email format<br>";
              else if(in_array("Emails don't match<br>", $error_array)) 
                    echo "Emails don't match<br>"; ?>


        <input type="password" name="reg_password" placeholder="Password" required>
        <br>


        <input type="password" name="reg_password2" placeholder="Confirm Password" required>
        <br>
        <?php if(in_array("Your passwords don't match<br>", $error_array)) 
                    echo "Your passwords don't match<br>";
              else if(in_array("Your password should contain one uppercase letter, one lowercase letter and one special character <br>", $error_array)) 
                    echo "Your password should contain one uppercase letter, one lowercase letter and one special character <br>";
              else if(in_array("Your password must be between 5 and 30 characters<br>", $error_array)) 
                    echo "Your password must be between 5 and 30 characters<br>"; ?>


        Birthday
        <br>
        <select name='day' required>
            <option disabled="disabled">Day</option>
            <option selected="true" value='1'>1</option>
            <option value='2'>2</option>
            <option value='3'>3</option>
            <option value='4'>4</option>
            <option value='5'>5</option>
            <option value='6'>6</option>
            <option value='7'>7</option>
            <option value='8'>8</option>
            <option value='9'>9</option>
            <option value='10'>10</option>
            <option value='11'>11</option>
            <option value='12'>12</option>
            <option value='13'>13</option>
            <option value='14'>14</option>
            <option value='15'>15</option>
            <option value='16'>16</option>
            <option value='17'>17</option>
            <option value='18'>18</option>
            <option value='19'>19</option>
            <option value='20'>20</option>
            <option value='21'>21</option>
            <option value='22'>22</option>
            <option value='23'>23</option>
            <option value='24'>24</option>
            <option value='25'>25</option>
            <option value='26'>26</option>
            <option value='27'>27</option>
            <option value='28'>28</option>
            <option value='29'>29</option>
            <option value='30'>30</option>
            <option value='31'>31</option>
            </select>

        <select name='month' required>
            <option disabled="disabled">Month</option>
            <option selected="true" value='jan'>Jan</option>
            <option value='feb'>Feb</option>
            <option value='mar'>Mar</option>
            <option value='apr'>Apr</option>
            <option value='may'>May</option>
            <option value='jun'>Jun</option>
            <option value='jul'>Jul</option>
            <option value='aug'>Aug</option>
            <option value='sep'>Sep</option>
            <option value='oct'>Oct</option>
            <option value='nov'>Nov</option>
            <option value='dec'>Dec</option>
        </select>

        <select name='year' required>
            <option disabled="disabled">Year</option>
            <option value='1990'>1990</option>
            <option value='1989'>1989</option>
            <option value='1988'>1988</option>
            <option value='1987'>1987</option>
            <option value='1986'>1986</option>
            <option value='1985'>1985</option>
            <option value='1984'>1984</option>
            <option value='1983'>1983</option>
            <option value='1982'>1982</option>
            <option value='1981'>1981</option>
            <option selected="true" value='1980'>1980</option>
            <option value='1979'>1979</option>
            <option value='1978'>1978</option>
            <option value='1977'>1977</option>
            <option value='1976'>1976</option>
            <option value='1975'>1975</option>
            <option value='1974'>1974</option>
            <option value='1973'>1973</option>
            <option value='1972'>1972</option>
            <option value='1971'>1971</option>
            <option value='1970'>1970</option>
            <option value='1969'>1969</option>
            <option value='1968'>1968</option>
            <option value='1967'>1967</option>
            <option value='1966'>1966</option>
            <option value='1965'>1965</option>
            <option value='1964'>1964</option>
            <option value='1963'>1963</option>
            <option value='1962'>1962</option>
            <option value='1961'>1961</option>
            <option value='1960'>1960</option>
            <option value='1959'>1959</option>
            <option value='1958'>1958</option>
            <option value='1957'>1957</option>
            <option value='1956'>1956</option>
            <option value='1955'>1955</option>
            <option value='1954'>1954</option>
            <option value='1953'>1953</option>
            <option value='1952'>1952</option>
            <option value='1951'>1951</option>
            <option value='1950'>1950</option>
            <option value='1949'>1949</option>
            <option value='1948'>1948</option>
            <option value='1947'>1947</option>
            <option value='1946'>1946</option>
            <option value='1945'>1945</option>
            <option value='1944'>1944</option>
            <option value='1943'>1943</option>
            <option value='1942'>1942</option>
            <option value='1941'>1941</option>
            <option value='1940'>1940</option>
            <option value='1939'>1939</option>
            <option value='1938'>1938</option>
            <option value='1937'>1937</option>
            <option value='1936'>1936</option>
            <option value='1935'>1935</option>
            <option value='1934'>1934</option>
            <option value='1933'>1933</option>
            <option value='1932'>1932</option>
            <option value='1931'>1931</option>
            <option value='1930'>1930</option>
            <option value='1929'>1929</option>
            <option value='1928'>1928</option>
            <option value='1927'>1927</option>
            <option value='1926'>1926</option>
            <option value='1925'>1925</option>
            <option value='1924'>1924</option>
            <option value='1923'>1923</option>
            <option value='1922'>1922</option>
            <option value='1921'>1921</option>
            <option value='1920'>1920</option>
            <option value='1919'>1919</option>
            <option value='1918'>1918</option>
        </select>
        <br>


        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" required> Male
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female"> Female
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="other"> Other
        <br>


        <input type="submit" name="register_button" value="Create Account">
        <br>

        <?php if(in_array("<span style='color: 14C800;'>You're all set! Go ahead and login!</span><br>", $error_array)) 
                    echo "<span style='color: 14C800;'>You're all set! Go ahead and login!</span><br>"; ?>

    </form>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could treat it the same as other and store it in session then check the value and print "selected" on the proper option tag like this

```
<select name='day' required>
    <option disabled="disabled">Day</option>
    <php?
        for($int i = 1; i <= 31; i++){
            $selected = $_SESSION['day'] == $i ? "selected='true'" : '';
            echo "<option value='$i' $selected>$i</option>";
        }
    ?>
    // Do the same for month and year
    // It's a bit different for gender but you should get the idea
</select>
```

Comment: is this how you mean

Comment: <select name='day' required>
   <option disabled="disabled">Day</option>
   <php?
          for($int i = 1; i <= 31; i++){
              $selected = $_SESSION['day'] == $i ? "selected='true'" : '';
              echo "<option value='$i' $selected></option>";
          }?>
   <option selected="true" value='1'>1</option>
   <option value='2'>2</option>
   <option value='3'>3</option>
   <option value='4'>4</option>
   <option value='5'>5</option>

Comment: @shi2056 did you store the value of selected day in $_SESSION['day']?

Comment: i did like for previous fields. have no prior knowledge of php. getting  a little confused

Comment: @shi2056 well then could you tell me in what way did my code not working?

Comment: thats why i provided the whole coding in my question to get accurate answer

Comment: @shi2056 I have edited my answer, please try again. Don't add any more option tag like in your second comment. Just try to copy it as is